# Is there a way in Drupal 7 to prevent the administrator from editing a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a module that creates (and updates) Drupal 7 nodes programmatically.

Since the content of the body these nodes is changed by a program at random intervals I do not want anyone, including the administrator, to be able to edit them.  Is there a way way to completely "turn-off" the interface that allows a administrator to edit a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like both of Clive's suggestions, but one more option is to simply disable the fields using HOOK_form_alter. This will work for the User 1 account too. I've used this recently to disable a specific field that I don't want anyone modifying.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    $form['body_field']['body']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    $form['body_field']['body']['#value'] = $form['body_field']['body']['#default_value'];
  }
}
```

Admittedly, this solution isn't ideal if you're using the built-in body field because of the teaser. But it works great if you want to disable editing of certain fields while leaving other aspects of the node editable and the page intact.

Comment: I am unable to get this to work for the built-in body field (which is what I need to disable). The problem may be that I am using wrong `$form_id` (I am using `mymodule-node-form` where "mymodule" is the name of my module).

Comment: Every Drupal form has a unique form ID. You can find it by inspecting the form and looking for a hidden field named "form_id". The value of that field is the form' form id.

In the case of a Drupal node form, it should be 'contenttype_node_form' where 'contenttype' is the machine name of your content type; e.g. 'article' or 'page'.

Comment: Thanks! I had the wrong `$form_id` (hyphens instead of underscores). Also, there seems to be no `body_field` array index in my form. The following disables the body field: `$form['body']['#disabled'] = TRUE;`  Its a toss-up between you and Clive which answer is "best" - but since I understand (I think) what goes on in yours, you get the 15 points.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a standard user with an administrator role you can implement [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in your custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if ($type == 'the_type' && $op == 'update') {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

If it's the 'super user' (user 1) you need to get a bit more creative as a lot of access checks are bypassed for that user.

You can implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to override the access callback for the node edit page, and provide your own instead:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/edit']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_node_edit_form_access';
}

function MYMODULE_node_edit_form_access($node) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  if ($type == 'my_type') {
    return FALSE;
  } 
  return node_access('update', $node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I could not get `hook_menu_alter` to work exactly as you suggest.
When used as shown, every time the callback function (MYMODULE_node_edit_form_access) is called, its argument ($node) was a string with value "update", which did no good.
However, if I add the following line: `$items['node/%node/edit']['access arguments'] = array(1)`, the `$node` arguments magically becomes an object and `$node->type` becomes meaningful.
To be honest, I do not know _why_ this works.  I stumbled across it by accident.  Any explanation that can shet light on why this works will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need them to be an administrator. That role, honestly, should be reserved for people with absolute control -- and even those people should not use it as their "main" account due to the potential for destroying things. Why not just make an "editor" role or something similar, and give all the permissions you need?

Comment: This is for a module that will be made available as contributed project at Drupal.org.  I have no way of knowing the skill levels of the admins that may use my module.  Rather than putting warnings in the code ("Don't edit nodes as admin!") I'd rather just disable that function.

Comment: Ah my apologies, assumed this was for a single project.